# Should I help my boss out?

Tags: management, work-environment, company-policy

I've recently got a new job at a company that is mainly sales based. My job is developing and maintaining the website, there are just two of us who do this (My boss and I).

The company is incredibly draconian and has some incredibly stupid rules and procedures, for example;

- When you arrive at work you must put your phone in a locker until the end of the day
- You must inform HR when you arrive for work and every time you take a break or go on lunch
- Computers are monitored 24/7
- Personal talk is not permitted

These are just a few of a long list, I would understand if the company handled sensitive data or had other security concerns but it's just a straight forward sales company.

I am without doubt going to leave as soon as the opportunity arises and i have no issue with burning bridges but i feel bad for my boss, He has no control over these rules and procedures but I know for a fact no half-decent developer will work for a company when these rules and procedures are in place as there are much better opportunity's out there.

Is it worth mentioning something when I leave or should I just stay quiet and not burn any bridges?

Comment: What is the "something" you want to mention and in what context? Do you want to tell your boss he should leave? Or tell him why you leave? Or offer him to help get another job? Those are very different things and what you can do also depends on your personal relationship with your boss.

Comment: I want to tell HR/the office administrators that they won't be able to hire/keep any half decent developer with the current policies and procedures they have in place, I have no personal relationship with my boss.

Comment: Confused about the title compared to the problem. Does your boss, specifically, need help? Or are you more concerned about the broad impact these policies may have on *any* employees in the future?

Comment: @dwizum Not specifically no but i like my boss as he has helped me allot and seems like a genuinely great guy but with the current policy's and procedures that are in place(that are out of his control) i feel like he will not be able to employ a half decent developer after i leave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably be asked why you're leaving or you may be invited to an exit interview. These are the best times to bring up that there are certain company practices you found uncomfortable or counter-productive. This can be voiced in such as way as to not sound hostile or too disparaging, and could even be backed up by comments or research from others in your field. It is nice that you're taking your manager's well-being into consideration but once you have given your feedback, it is up to the company to decide what is next. Whether or not your feedback is interpreted as 'bridge burning' is again up to the company to decide.

If you are calm, honest and professional about it (*even if the company itself is not*), your next employer will be understanding of your reasons and not think negatively of it.

I too have worked with companies that have quite 'draconian' practices when it comes to IT and development and it only took a disastrous lack of employee retention to make them realise they had to change. If you do decide to give your reasons, it would be best not to hope they will act upon it right away, or at all. It may sound harsh but you must think of your own career and trust your boss to decide his future himself.

Comment: I highly doubt i'll be asked why or invited to an exit interview as i've been here for less than a month, I don't have any resentment towards the company or any intention of coming across as rude or hostile as the company itself and the people within it are great to work with/for but the policy's and procedures are shoddy at best. from my understanding there have been 3 employee's in my position before me, all of whom have left shortly after getting employed.